# Why does the Linux kernel dump a <unset>.core?

Tags: linux, core-dump

I'm working on Linux 4.0.6, and I've activated the coredump and using `%e.core` pattern.
On my machine I see `<unset>.core` in the core folder. Can someone explain me what does `<unset>` mean and how can I prevent this?

Comment: Read more about [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

%e in the core pattern maps to the executable filename, which is essentially equivalent to the `comm` field in /proc.  Under some circumstances, this field in the internal process structure in the kernel can be empty (namely, if argv[0] is an empty string, and for a very short period of time during a fork() call), and if the process crashes while that is the case, you can get a core file with a name like you specified.  For what it's worth, I have found that %E (the executable path) is a bit more reliable, as that can't be manipulated by the process itself.